# How to hide links in navigation bar(Home page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="console-nav-bar">
    <ul class="px-nav-actions nav navbar-nav">
enter code here<li class="nav-item"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" style="display:none"><a href="tasks">Manage</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="Send">Send</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="Receive">Receive</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Currently i am using below code to hide links on home page.

```
$(".px-nav-actions li").eq(0).hide();
                $(".px-nav-actions li").eq(1).hide();
                $(".px-nav-actions li").eq(2).hide();
                $(".px-nav-actions li").eq(3).hide();
```

Issue :- When i load home page. I am able to see above links for few seconds in navigation bar and then it is hiding.

How to stop showing these links on home page?

Comment: You could hide them by default. What's the intended behavior for them to be shown/hidden? They show briefly because the page loads before the javascript fires.

Comment: hmmm....Are you JQuery codes in a window.onload function?It may wait for the window to load before execute (if this is so)...notwithstanding the time taken for httprequest to complete and load the external script....

Answer (score 0):

It works on my side:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="console-nav-bar">
        <ul class="px-nav-actions nav navbar-nav">
    enter code here<li class="nav-item"><a href="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" style="display:none"><a href="tasks">Manage</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="Send">Send</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="Receive">Receive</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(".px-nav-actions li").eq(0).hide();
    $(".px-nav-actions li").eq(1).hide();
    $(".px-nav-actions li").eq(2).hide();
    $(".px-nav-actions li").eq(3).hide();
</script>
```

Also, you don't need to hide them 1 by 1, you could just have done:

```
$(".px-nav-actions li").hide(); // hides all
```